# Regras de auth com NodeJS + Passport + MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport-js

Vamos a duvida. Estou usando como exemplo um blog. Tenho o Administrador. Ele faz um CRUD completo dentro do sistema. Além dele tenho o Editor e Revisor. O Editor cria posts no blog, mas não publica. E o Revisor, vê e sugere edição no post criado pelo Editor. O Administrador faz qualquer coisa. Cria post, da permissão ao Editor e Revisor. Apaga, bloqueia Usuários. O Editor cria e atualiza post. E o Revisor só sugere alterações no post. É um sistema de nível de acesso de usuário. Existem vários tutoriais sobre o uso do passport, mas nenhum que ajude nessa duvida.

Estou usando essa base: [passport-mongo](https://github.com/tutsplus/passport-mongo)

Answer (score 0):

JWT não resolve este problema, o JWT é uma especificação [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) de troca de mensagens usando JSON, Tokens e como fazer isso de forma criptografada.
O que você quer é controlar níveis de acesso a usuário, você pode continuar fazendo o que faria com PHP, como citou, e fazer a troca de mensagens entre sua API e seu APP "usando" JWT

Answer (score 0):

Na hora de criar o token do JWT, você pode armazenar informações dentro dele, como o id do usuário, o nome dele e o **nível de acesso dele**. Tendo o nível de acesso dele, você pode criar um middleware que checa se o nível de acesso daquela JWT é válido ou inválido, e caso seja válido, permite o acesso à aquela rota.

No código abaixo, eu criei um middleware que checa se o JWT é válido, e caso seja, armazena as informações dele no req.usuario.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  jwt.verify(req.headers['x-access-token'], process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decodedToken) => {
    if (err) return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Você não tem autorização para continuar!' });

    req.usuario = decodedToken;
    return next();
  });
};
```

No código abaixo, criei um middleware que checa se o nível de acesso do req.usuario.

```
module.exports = (nivel) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.usuario.nivel || req.usuario.nivel < nivel) return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Você não tem autorização para continuar!' });
    return next();
  };
};
```

Se quiser um exemplo, completo, tenho um repositório que uso para estudar React.js, mas já implementei a parte de autenticação.
https://github.com/andreolvr/aprendendo-react

Os códigos que te interessam estão em server/middleware e no app.js, para ver como aplico esse middleware nas rotas.